# Window Location Characters Remove JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have several urls ended with “?pid=154”

My urls are like

mysitename/?pid=154
mysitename/abc.html?pid=154
mysitename/abc/abcd.html?pid=154
mysitename/abc/abcd/abcdef.html?pid=154

I want to remove ?pid=154

I need the below results
mysitename
mysitename/abc.html
mysitename/abc/abcd.html
mysitename/abc/abcd/abcdef.html

I tried with

```
    var my_w_loc = window.location.href;
    if (my_w_loc.indexOf(?pid=154)) {
        curl = my_w_loc.replace('?pid=154', '');
    }
```

Comment: In the .indexOf call, you have to wrap ?pid=154 in single or double quotes

Comment: It's `my_w_loc.indexOf("?pid=154") > -1`.

Answer (score 0):

`replace` takes strings as arguments. You don't even need to check if your string contains the substring, you can do everything in one line with:

`let curl = window.location.href.replace('?pid=154', '')`